# UITableViewController с мульти datasource и кастомными мультиячейками на UIPageViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Не кодил толком 1,5 месяца. Туплю сильно :).

Вообщем вопрос: Есть табы (кастомные кнопки вверху). Под ними containerView -> pageViewController -> TableViewController (OrdersTableViewController, пустой). 5ть кастомных ячеек для каждого таба. Ячейки сделал на табличном контроллере(OrdersTableViewController) и присвоил каждой уникальный идентитификатор.
Наследовал 5ть классов от табличного контроллера (OrdersTableViewController). Переопределил методы делегата и датасоурса в каждом классе. В pageViewController создаю объекты этих классов (регистрирую ячейку с определенным идентификатором). Наследованные таблицы пустые :(

Что делаю не правильно? и вообще как правильно? Не могу понять как оно должно работать :) С архитектурной точки зрения правильно, может что-то не так с ячейками?. Может не видит ячейки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наследованный класс от OrdersTableViewController (на OrdersTableViewController размещены 5ть кастомный ячеек)

```
#import "OpenOrders.h"
#import "OpenOrderCell.h"

#define OPENTASKCELL        @"openTasksCell"


@implementation OpenOrders

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
    [self.tableView registerClass:[OpenOrderCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:OPENTASKCELL];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    OpenOrderCell *cell = (OpenOrderCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:OPENTASKCELL forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [OpenOrderCell new];
    }
    cell.type.text = @"sjdgshdg";

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

@end
```

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath или любой другой метод датасурса вызывается вообще? и если нет, то определены ли делегат и датасурс

Comment: Вызывается, даже ячейка создается, но (пустая) внутри все элементы nil. Может дело из-за того что сами кастомные ячейки находятся на основном контроллере (ни к чему не привязаны, только к своим кастомным классам).

Comment: а если заменить кастомную на обычную и задавать cell.textLabel.text что нибудь видно?

Comment: Нет. Пока что сделал 5ть отдельных контроллеров с таблицей и в каждой свою ячейку. Это скорее всего костыль, но пока другого выхода я не вижу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае лучше всего будет использовать 1 табличный контроллер(если во всех табах он одинаковый, а меняются только ячейки), а кастомные ячейки реализовать в отдельных xib файлах, зарегистрировать их в табличном контроллере с помощью метода таблицы `registerNib` и в методе `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` загружать нужные ячейки в зависимости от выбранного таба